# I'm trying to create separate bar charts for 5 categorical variables in a dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that contains 4 columns of data. Each of these columns is a character variable containing 5 different values ( i.e. column1 contains the values A,B,C,D or E .   column2 contains the values EXCELLENT , VERY GOOD, GOOD, AVERAGE, and POOR.  columns 3 and 4  are similar.

I'm trying to get a separate bar chart for each of the columns by using the below for loop. Unfortunately, it only provides me with the bar chart for column 4. It does not provide the bar chart for the previous 3 columns. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```py
categorical_attribs=list(CharacterVarDF)
    
for i in categorical_attribs:
    
    CharacterVarDF [i].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set up matplotlib subplots with number of rows and columns. Then in loop, assign each column bar plot to each `ax`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6), ncols=1, nrows=CharacterVarDF.shape[1])

for col, ax in zip(CharacterVarDF.columns, np.ravel(axes)):
    CharacterVarDF[col].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, rot=0, title=col)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

To demonstrate with random data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import rc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(52021)
env_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "planetary_boundaries": np.random.choice(
        ["ocean", "land", "biosphere", "atmosphere", 
         "climate", "soil", "ozone", "freshwater"], 50),
    "species": np.random.choice(
        ["invertebrates", "vertebrates", "plants", "fungi & protists"], 50),
    "tipping_points": np.random.choice(
        ["Arctic Sea Ice", "Greenland ice sheet", "West Antarctica ice sheet",
         "Amazon Rainforest", "Boreal forest", "Indian Monsoon", 
         "Atlantic meridional overturning circulation", 
         "West African Monsoon", "Coral reef"], 50)
})

rc('font', **{'family' : 'Arial'})
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=env_df.shape[1], figsize=(7,7))

for col, ax in zip(env_df.columns, np.ravel(axes)):
    env_df[col] = env_df[col].str.replace(" ", "\n")
    env_df[col].value_counts(sort=False).sort_index().plot(
        kind='bar', ax=ax, color='g', rot=0,
        title=col.replace("_", " ").title(),
    )

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
plt.clf()
plt.close()
```

[image: Plot Output]